# Asp,net form with order of preference

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying do a form in which the user can fill a selection form of academies with order of preferences.
The record should store in the database in this table like this:

tblAcademy_selection

```
   stud_id Acad_id order_preference
   --------------------------------
    1      1          1
    1      2          2
    1      3          3
    1      5          4
    1      4          5
```

I have list the academy via object data source in a bound field of a grid view and I have a field choice for the choice preference :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gdvAcadSelec" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="acad_Id" DataSourceID="srcAcademy"
             OnRowDataBound="gdvAcadSelec_RowDataBound"
            CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered"
            EnableViewState="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="acad_name"
                    HeaderText="Academy" SortExpression="acad_name" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Choice">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPref" runat="server">
                          
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="srcAcademy"
            TypeName="dataAccessLayer"
            SelectMethod="getAcademy"
            runat="server" />
```

I was thinking to put the number of choice preference via a dropdown list but with this way the  system will not be good.

What I want is like a check box but instead of the tick, a number will place in the box depending on number of choice selected. The number of preference in box should be dynamic example: the first selection of the student will automatically be 1 ,then second selection should input a 2 and so on. If he unselect the 2 for example, his next select order of preference should remain 2 as no 2 yet been place.
The tick should be ascending way

I have search everywhere how to do this and I did not found it.
Are there other way to make this academy order of preference form?

Comment: How are you planning to facilitate the selection of academy to the user?

Comment: What do you mean by that please?

Comment: I am planning to make this selection form which was done on paper to a computerized form.

Answer (score 0):

I think your table should be updated to include a primary key. It would just make some things easier. (Edit: I suppose you could make all 3 fields the PK. Up to you.)

I don't know what data type the order_preference field is. I'm assuming number or int for now, but text would work pretty much the same way.

```
tblAcademy_selection

AcademySelectionID stud_id Acad_id order_preference
---------------------------------------------------
1                     1       1          1
2                     1       2          2
3                     1       3          3
4                     1       5          4
5                     1       4          5
```

Your gridview should use the table above.

Make the academy_id field a a template field with a dropdown, and the order_preference field a template field with a textbox. The PK and stud_id should not even need to be visible, depending on how you deal with the student id (which might be automated, it's hard to tell).

The academy dropdown template-field will have it's own datasource, similar to the way you are doing it.

This gridview should be updateable without a problem. You can enter the preference order as simple text. (I can imagine another way, with a dropdown, but it could get ugly.) You'll just have to validate what is entered.

The main thing is to use tblAcademy_selection for the gridview.

Hth.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i was also  thinking about a drop down in the order of preference field,do you think this can create a problem?

Comment: Possibly, for ex, how many numbers do you put? If you can determine that, or don't care about adding more later, go for it.

Comment: The range of order of preference should from 1-12

Comment: The problem i get is to retrieve the id of the dropdown field in the gridview,how can i do that?

Comment: Sorry, not going to go through everything step by step.